# retrieving all the contact photos in one shot in android

Tags: android, photos

Is there a way to retrieve all the contact photos in one go? I do not want to get photo one by one by using contact id.
Is it possible to do this?

Thx!
Rahul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that you can get ALL of the photos with one Query. That would be a really big cursor object I feel, plus everything I've read about actually storing photos in a database is troublesome.

Instead you can easily just query all the contacts ids and grab the photos via

```
public static Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long  id) {
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
if (input == null) {
    return null;
}
return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);}
```

Comment: I did the same thing... but it was taking hell of a long time to get the data... I have some 1200 contacts in my phone... and it was talking around 15-20 secs to get all the data. If I just remove the load pictures call... all the contacts were  getting loaded in 1 sec. Please let me know if there is any other way.

Comment: So it sounds like you will have to do a mix of throttling your calls and image caching. I don't know your application, but there isn't any possible way you are displaying 1200 contacts at once. You will have to only call the photos that you need to display (may the next few also) instead of getting everything at once